Error in the code when compiling an empty project for stm32
I'm trying to compile an empty project created automatically by Eclipse with the toolkit that allows me to write code for Arm, I additionally installed the Arm GNU ToolChain compiler, as well as MinGW and CDT Main Features + CDT Optional Features. Now, when I create a new project for STM32F1, without changing anything in the code, I fail to compile and get an error:
enter image description here
I would be grateful if you could help me solve this problem!
I tried to search for this error on the Internet, but I can't find anything, I don't understand what the problem is

You would be better to use STM32CubeIDE which can be downloaded for free from ST's website. It includes an IDE based on Eclipse, and will give you a working project to start from.
